# Zombie children of init

Tags: linux, process, kernel, init, zombie-process

How zombie process can be a child of init? Isn't init supposed to waitpid on all its children?

I occasionally run into zombie processes whose parent is init. The theory says that when process dies, it remains zombie until it's parent wait's or waitpid's on it. If parent is dead, then process is adopted by init and it does the waiting.

I am looking at such process now. I attached to init with strace. I do see that init wakes up once in a while and waitpid's on its child processes. I do see however that it skips it's zombie child. I am wondering how that is possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We can have different implementation for waitpid().
If the kernel was designed in a way that it should ignore the zombie threads then it might be possible that init will skip its zombie thread and will cleanup its data structure in later stage.

For more details you can refer to man page of waitpid()

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html